# How to find the inverse function

Tags: inverse-function

For this function: $f(x)=x\exp(ax)$

what is the inverse function $f^{-1}(\cdot)$?

Comment: Did you prove this function has an inverse?

Comment: $\dfrac{W(ax)}{a}$ where $W$ is the [lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  It is a non-elementary function.

Comment: What do you mean by exp? Do you mean, ^?

Comment: @MathLover $\exp$ is a standard name for the natural exponential $x \mapsto e^x$.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Then I agree with JMoravitz.